# When to scale up an Azure Standard Instance Size

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have 19 websites running on Azure Standard Websites, with the instance size set to Small.

Right now I can't scale out to multiple instances (or use auto scale) because some of these sites are legacy sites that won't play nice across multiple sites.

The sites running now are fairly basic, but there are 3 sites that are growing fast, and I don't want to have them all bogged down because of the small instance, but I also don't want to pay for a large instance if I don't have to.

How to know when I should scale up to a medium or large instance?
There doesn't seem to be any way to see CPU load in the portal, only CPU time.

Comment: As an aside to the "some sites that won't play nice" - I wish there was a concise list of the "legacy bits" that won't work when scaling out on azure, rather than up.  Or is it auto-magical?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scale up, you need to scale out. you can set CPU metric and set the number if instances you need for that metric - 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I can't scale out at the moment because some of the sites have legacy bits that will cause issues on multiple instances. What I need is some sort of metric that shows how well the VM is coping and if I need a bigger VM